# Getting classNameBindings working with a button #view in handlebars with ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to get a class to appear on a specific button withing a handlebar view based on a property binding.  I'm doing something that is like the Todo app that ember.js has on their site (http://emberjs.com/examples/todos/) and I'm trying to make the "Clear Completed" button disappear based on the value of a property.

I have a jsfiddle showing kind of what I'm going for here (http://jsfiddle.net/boushley/XEdNg/).  If I add a className inside of the #view tag it shows up fine.  But if I add a clasNameBindings it doesn't work the way I expect.  Am I going about this wrong or is something broken here?

Aaron

Comment: This question refers to deprecated code from a pre 1.0 version of EmberJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discussed this here https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/322 and one of the people on the project helped with this, giving a clear way of how to perform this here https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/322#issuecomment-3332477 (http://jsfiddle.net/aNZSD/) In essence I needed to create a view that extends ButtonView and place the properties I want on this new view. This is the way it should work, I just wasn't seeing this properly.

Hope this makes it clearer for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I remember I had similar problems with `classNameBindings` too.

Try this instead: http://guides.sproutcore20.com/using_handlebars.html#binding-class-names-with-bindattr.

```
// Javascript for the view
App.AlertView = SC.View.extend({
  priority: "p4",
  isUrgent: true
});

// Template
<div {{bindAttr class="priority"}}>
  Warning!
</div>

// Emits the following HTML
<div class="p4">
  Warning!
</div>
```

If you just want to show/hide the button, then try binding the `isVisible` property.

```
isVisibleBinding: 'App.pageController.myProperty'
```

Hope this helps.